# How to check if a function is partially differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Sorry for this basic request. $$$$Could you please tell me how to check if a function is partially differentiable (I don't know if this is the right term), both over an interval, as well as at a point? I tried checking on the Net, but all I got to know was that the partial derivatives exist throughout if (?) the function is differentiable. $$$$
Could somebody please shed light on this? Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to show that partial derivatives do exist at a point, or on an interval, is to use the fact that if two functions are differentiable then their sum, product, and composition (when defined) is differentiable. In other words, you build the function out of simple pieces that are known to be differentiable -- like polynomials or trigonometric functions -- by using simple operations -- addition, multiplication, and composition. Then there are theorems that the resulting function is also differentiable.

For instance, here's a rigorous proof that for the function 
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{x^2+e^y}{\sin(xy^3)},
$$
partial derivatives exist at all points where the function is defined, i.e.,
where $\sin(xy^3)\neq0$.

1. The functions $(x,y)\mapsto x^2$ (polynomial) and $(x,y)\mapsto e^y$ (exponential) are differentiable everywhere.
2. Therefore the sum $(x,y)\mapsto x^2 + e^y$ is differentiable everywhere.
3. The functions $t\mapsto\sin t$ (trigonometric) and $(x,y)\mapsto xy^3$ (polynomial) are differentiable everywhere.
4. Therefore the composition $(x,y)\mapsto\sin(xy^3)$ is differentiable everywhere.
5. Therefore the ratio $(x,y)\mapsto (x^2 + e^y)/\sin(xy^3) = f(x,y)$ is differentiable *everywhere the denominator does not vanish*.